# Need query for JOIN four tables with some conditions?

Tags: sql, mysqli

I have the following four tables:

1) mls_user
2) mls_category
3) bonus_point
4) mls_entry

In mls_user table values are like below:

```
*-------------------------*
| id | store_id | name    |
*-------------------------*
| 1  |    101   | sandeep |
| 2  |    101   | gagan   |
| 3  |    102   | santosh |
| 4  |    103   | manu    |
| 5  |    101   | jagveer |
*-------------------------*
```

In mls_category table values are like below:

```
*---------------------------------*
| cat_no |  store_id |  cat_value |
*---------------------------------*
|   20   |   101     |     1      |
|   21   |   101     |     4      |
|   30   |   102     |     1      |
|   31   |   102     |     2      |
|   40   |   103     |     1      |
|   41   |   103     |     1      |
*---------------------------------*
```

In bonus_point table values are like below:

```
*-----------------------------------*
| user_id | store_id |  bonus_point |
|   1     |   101    |     10       |
|   4     |   101    |      5       |
*-----------------------------------*
```

In mls_entry table values are like below:

```
*-------------------------------------------------------*
| user_id | store_id |  category |  distance |  status  |
*-------------------------------------------------------*
|    1    |   101    |    20     |    10     | Approved |
|    1    |   101    |    21     |    40     | Approved |
|    1    |   101    |    20     |    10     | Approved |
|    2    |   101    |    20     |     5     | Approved |
|    3    |   102    |    30     |    10     | Approved |
|    3    |   102    |    31     |    80     | Approved |
|    4    |   101    |    20     |    15     | Approved |
*-------------------------------------------------------*
```

And I want below output:

```
*--------------------------------------------------*
|  user name  | Points | bonus Point | Total Point |    
*--------------------------------------------------*
|   Sandeep   |   30   |     10      |    40       |
|   Santosh   |   30   |     0       |    30       |
|   Manu      |   15   |     5       |    20       |
|   Gagan     |   5    |     0       |     5       |
|   Jagveer   |   0    |     0       |    0        |
*--------------------------------------------------*
```

I tell the calculation of how the points will come for user Sandeep.
Points =  ((10+10)/1 + 40/4)=30
Here 1 and 4 is cat value which comes from mls_category.

I am using below code for a particular user but when i

```
 SELECT sum(t1.totald/c.cat_value) as total_distance 
     FROM mls_category c 
       join (
         select sum(distance) totald, user_id, category 
           FROM mls_entry 
           WHERE user_id=1 AND store_id='101' AND status='approved' 
           group by user_id, category) t1 on c.cat_no = t1.category
```

I have created tables in online for checking
[DEMO](https://rextester.com/MRGYN34547)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computing the points (other than the bonus points) requires a separate join between the `mls_entry` and `mls_category` tables.  I would do this in a separate subquery, and then join this to the larger query.

Here is one approach:

```
SELECT
    u.name,
    COALESCE(t1.points, 0) AS points,
    COALESCE(b.bonus_point, 0) AS bonus_points,
    COALESCE(t1.points, 0) + COALESCE(b.bonus_point, 0) AS total_points
FROM mls_user u
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT e.user_id, SUM(e.distance / c.cat_value) AS points
    FROM mls_entry e
    INNER JOIN mls_category c
        ON e.store_id = c.store_id AND e.category = c.cat_no
    GROUP BY e.user_id
) t1
    ON u.id = t1.user_id
LEFT JOIN bonus_point b
    ON u.id = b.user_id
ORDER BY
    total_points DESC;
```

This is the output I am getting from the above query in the demo you setup:

[image]

The output does not match exactly, because you have (perhaps) a typo in Santosh's data in your question, or otherwise the expected output in your question has a typo.

Comment: Great bro, You are my hero. Just one question I want to order descending order by total_points means Santosh will come first, then sandeep will come like this. so where I put the order by

Comment: @SantoshKhatri Use `ORDER BY total_points DESC`.  LOL, just realized you are Santosh!

Comment: Thanks a lot. you are my super hero. you save my life.

Comment: one more question supposes I want to show records according to store_id means I want to show records only store_id '101' my new records will show only for  Sandeep, Santosh and jagveer because their store_id is 101 then where i put the condition.